# Merge arrays, `x` and `y`, in correspondence of equal elements of `x`

Tags: arrays, r

Let as consider two arrays of the same length like, e.g., the following

```
x<-c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
y<-c(1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6)
```

I would like to obtain a third array `z` in this way. If there exists an index `i` such that `x[i]=x[i+1]=...=x[i+k]` for some `k>1`, then `z[i]` is the maximum number between `y[i],y[i+1],...,y[i+k]`. Otherwise, for `j` different from `i`, `z[j]` is equal to `y[j]`. In our example we have

```
z=c(2,4,4,4,5,6,6,6)
```

I can perform this operation by means a for loop and an if-else statement but I wonder if there's a more efficient solution for it.

Comment: For `i == 2` there are no `x[i + k] == x[i]` thus `z[j] == y[i]` which is 2 but not 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still a loop but using `sapply`

```
sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) {
    #Compare values from ith index to end of the array with x[i]
    inds = x[min(i+1, length(x)):length(x)] == x[i]
    #If there are any similar values return the max y value
    if(any(inds))  max(y[i:(which.max(!inds) - 1 + i)])
    #return the corresponding y value
    else   y[i]
})

#[1] 2 2 4 4 4 4 5 6 6 6
```